# How can I reduce the spark while connecting the battery?

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, battery-operated, spark, drone

I've been working on a drone that works on a 12S batter (maximum 50.4V.) I am using an Amass XT90 anti spark Connector to connect the battery to the power distribution board (PDB.)

The drone has an electronic speed control (ESC) which needs low equivalent series resistance (ESR) capacitors on the input side to reduce a spike in voltage which might damage the MOSFETs. Since these capacitors have high capacitance, they create a short circuit for an instant at the moment I connect battery which creates a big spark. This spark will reduce the life of the connector and I have to clean the soot every time to ensure lower contact resistance.

Is there any device which I can put inline which ramps up the voltage slowly?

Comment: It depends on the context and your schematic. Generally this is called "inrush current limiter" and can be designed in many different ways. NTC thermistors for example. Could you post a simple schematic of the power part of your board? Including batteries and the location of the caps.

Comment: Google _pre-charge_. Basically a resistor in series and some means to bypass it once secondary side is charged.

Comment: which could mean plugging in a secondary connector first, that has a resistor, before plugging in the main one